# How to get XML objects into Swing to add properties to it

Tags: xml, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I'm new to swing and XML. I tried asking question about this earlier also but it happens that no one is quite able to answer it. Can anyone tell me if there is a way to get objects of XML(mainly, JButton) into swing to assign them properties?

Thanks.

Swing Code:

```
XMLDecoder xmlDecoder = new XMLDecoder(new FileInputStream ("MasterXML.xml"));
Object frame = xmlDecoder.readObject();
System.out.println("It reached here");
Object button = xmlDecoder.readObject();
System.out.println("It reached here 2");
((JButton) button).addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Siri");
    }
    });
System.out.println("It reached here 3");
xmlDecoder.close();
```

Comment: Can you share your code ? for better understand?

Comment: Shared. Please check.

Comment: pls check my answer below do some modification in there

Comment: `I tried asking question about this earlier also but it happens that no one is quite able to answer it.` - yes, well you need to ask a reasonable question if you expect help. First of all you need to post your [mcve] showing how you "encode" the button to the XML file and how you "decode" the button and how you add the decoded button to a frame. Then you need to state what the actual problem is with your code. Do you get any errors? How do you know it is not working. There is no real trick. You use the XMLEncoder to write an object to a file and the XMLDecoder to read the object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are look something like this

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse("/home/riddhish/developerworkspace/SplitString/src/com/updatexmlwithjava/two.xml");

NodeList username = doc.getElementsByTagName("username");           
System.out.println("username ="+username.item(0).getTextContent());
NodeList password = doc.getElementsByTagName("password");           
System.out.println("password ="+password.item(0).getTextContent());
```